# Why do i have to specify any HTTP status codes in general ? What is the benefit of it?

Tags: javascript, http

I've read some articles about HTTP statuses, and i'm still not sure why i should specify them in my app. Let's say a user provided wrong password while trying to login. In my express app i can send response in those ways :

```
 res.status(401).json({ message: 'Wrong password' })
```

or

```
res.json({ message: 'Wrong password' })
```

Then my application logic is based on the  `message` value.
I understand that in the second case the status code is going to be `200 OK` , but why should i care about it ?

Comment: HTTP status codes are a standardized part of the web, so everyone knows to expect them and what they mean. That's not true of the object `{ message: 'Wrong password" }`.

Comment: If you want your application to conform to web standards, then you should send the appropriate status codes. If you don't care, then you can do whatever. Don't expect all tools to work correctly for your application, though.

Comment: @VLAZ Could you elaborate on tools  ?  Let's say the app is not going to provide any future apis

Comment: @Noob Tools like browsers, proxies, rest clients, etc. Supposedly you are not using your app only from your own software?

Comment: @Noob *any* tools that work with the web. Somebody might write a userscript for your app (might even be you), webcrawlers might visit it, you might want to test it using some sort of automation tool, somebody else might want to test it, you might want to scrape some data from your own service for some reason (e.g., want to build up a constantly updating live-like data for testing), maybe you add a library or something to your project. Any and all web interactions are likely to use the status codes and *most* would be outside your hands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many reasons.  A few off the top of my head:

- Caching.  [`2xx` responses are cacheable by default.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)  You shouldn't be sending a `200` response for an error or it may look to the user like they can never login!
- Compatibility with client libraries.  It sure is nice to be able to use [things that are standards compliant](https://github.com/axios/axios), so you can maybe do a `.catch()` and show the user an error rather than having a ton of custom logic to figure out whether the response was good or not.
- Status codes also come from other code in the chain.  You're often not just talking to your app, but usually [a proxy on your end](https://www.nginx.com/).  And then, there may be *several* [proxies between the client and you](https://www.wingate.com/products/wingate/features.php?cat_id=1#Transparent%20proxying).  Why should your client code have to figure out both your application-level signalling *and* the status code signalling when they can be one of the same?  Ask someone with satellite internet... they'll tell you about what a pain intermediate proxies can be when people don't follow the standards.
- Automatic error logging.  Surely you use [some system](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) to track errors in your system, right?  If you use standard HTTP response codes, they can be categorized automatically.

Comment: +1 for the caching comment. Your browser **relies** on those status codes - if everything is status 200, then it can't tell those responses apart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to care about HTTP because you are relying on it for your application to work. Using the appropriate HTTP verbs and status codes is necessary for this, allowing e.g. middleware or browser caches to do their work. You don't want your error message to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of reasons. At the highest, clearest level - it's **accessibility** / **universality**.

Consider a few scenarios:

- What if the consumer of the request doesn't read the same language as your app?
- Your web browser has immense power when it comes to intelligently sorting HTTP requests / responses. Many HTTP `2xx` responses are cached; so on and so forth.
- Many intermediary services, from firewalls to traffic filters and everything between, rely on status codes to make various calculations they need
- Reliability. It's much safer to rely on finding a `401 Not Authorized` than it is to rely on `wrong password` in your message field. What if you change the string, even just adding a `.` or captilizing something?